# How do I create custom paging on a repeater with a SQLDataSource?

Tags: c#, sql, repeater, sqldatasource

While looking on stack overflow a member suggested [this tutorial](http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/66-repeater-paging-with-an-sqldatasource-in-aspnet.html) . I looks like it may actually work but it is incomplete.

at the bottom of his codebehind he is using a

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) { }
```

which he removed for clarity. I tried to resolve it by filling it in this way but it did not work

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
    {
        if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

        foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
        {
            Control controlToReturn =
                FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
            if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The other issue surrounding this is that since the post is so old I doubt its still being monitored.

Answer (score 1):

I tried working with that tutorial a few months ago and found it a little too brittle for what I needed.  I eventually discovered [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) by Julie Lerman and it has since served me well.

One of the cool things about paging is that its relatively simple to implement once you understand the variables that you have to keep track of.  Julie's article uses the entity framework, but the concepts she discusses are nearly identical to those that you'll need to understand when implementing the feature with an SQLDataSource.

Long story short, you only need to keep track of two things: how many records you want displayed per page, what page you're on, and an optional third variable - your data's sorting.  Once you've got those down, you're just a stone's throw away from a fully functional, paging-abled repeater. :)

**Edit** - If Julie's use of the entity framework is a bit too abstract for your situation, you can refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx) which more closely resembles your specific implementation.